# Does SQL Server 2016 Express support Always Encrypted?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

Is SQL Server's new encryption "at rest and in motion" feature available in the Express version of SQL Server 2016?

Comment: It's hard to give a definitive answer before it actually RTMs, but for now the answer is much closer to "no". You can download a RC build and check for yourself.

Comment: Based on http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/A/2/8A2BC8C5-BBA0-4A9C-90BC-AC957D3454D9/SQL_Server_2016_Editions_datasheet.pdf it would appear that it's only an enterprise edition feature.

Comment: Always encrypted is now supported even in [LocalDB](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/11/sql-server-2016/big-deal-sp1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *Always Encrypted* feature is not available in express edition. It is available in SQL Server **Enterprise** and **Developer** editions only.

> **Edit:** With 2016 SP1, *Always Encrypted* feature is now available with **all** versions of SQL Servers. More on what's new in SP1 [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/11/sql-server-2016/big-deal-sp1) (Edit courtsey-@Ender2050)

More details on feature comparison for different editions of SQL Server 2016  - 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions

Comment: So another case of "why not in the standard edition, MS?". Excellent :(

Comment: @Fetchezlavache It *is* supported now, even in Express - sorry, even in [LocalDB](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/11/sql-server-2016/big-deal-sp1)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - that's for that! I'd missed this announcement completely. This will be *huge* for us :)

Answer (score 7):

Always Encrypted is supported in all versions of SQL Server 2016 SP1, according to the link posted above by Yogi. This must have changed recently. 2016-Q4.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @ender205 from your point. Edited my answer with SP1 updated.

Comment: It's also supported in [LocalDB](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/11/sql-server-2016/big-deal-sp1)